# Isomorphism of $l^{\infty}(X)$ and Stone-Cech

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

If $X$ is a discrete metric space, then $l^{\infty}(X)$ is isomorphic to $C(\beta X)$ where $\beta X$ is the Stone-Cech compactification. Given an $f \in l^{\infty}(X)$, f is continuous because $X$ is discrete, then there is a unique extention $g \in C(\beta X)$. Is it the isomorphism?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is exactly the isomorphism.  It is easy to see that the map you describe is a bijection.  The fact that it is an isomorphism (of pretty much any structure you would want) then easily follows from the fact that $X$ is dense in $\beta X$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's right. Note that the extension is unique, so this map is well-defined. Also, injectivity is clear, extending different functions yields different results. All continuous functions on $\beta X$ are bounded, so restricting to $X$ yields a bounded function on $X$ too (the inverse ), having the same norm as $X$ is dense in $\beta X$. So we have a linear isometry.